# Does it matter if I freeze dough before proofing?

Tags: freezing, dough, pizza, proofing

I made some pizza dough today and only used 1/3 of it. The other portions I decided to put in the freezer to use later on. I froze them before proofing though. Does this matter? Should I have let them proof first, then freeze?

I'm mostly worried that this might affect the future proofing, once I get them out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can honestly say I've done this on many occasions. Especially for pizza dough, I defrost in the fridge for 24 hours in a cling filmed bowl which allows it to prove slowly through the day. Never once had an issue with it.